# How to select each loop generated ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap

I am making this app that can download photo's from the `Unsplash API`.

To do so, I have to create a click function that selects the id of the button, and then calls the `JSON` download link.

This works great, but now I am loading a bunch of Unsplash IMG's with a search term, mapping over each response in the `JSON` API and putting them into Bootstrap cards. I already figured out a way to create a new ID for each IMG response, but now I need to be able to click each photo's download button and download that SPECIFIC ITEM ONLY.

I tried doing so with a class instead but this does not give the ability to download a specific unique photo.

Here is the documented code:

```
// Search for Photos

$('form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // API Calls
    let input = document.getElementById("search").value;
    let $submitButton = $('#submit');
    let searchPhoto = API + 'search/photos?' + client_id + '&page=1&query=' + input;

// Ajax part
$.getJSON(searchPhoto, function (response) {

    // Create beginning of Bootstrap card
    let photoHTML = '<div class="col-12 col-sm-6">'

    // Loop over each response photo, putting it into a unique card
    $.each(response.results, function (i, photo) {
        // Card background
        let photoBackground = photo.urls.regular;
        // Download link
        let download = photo.links.download + "?force=true";
        // Create a link to be clicked by the download button
        link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = download;
        link.download = 'Download.jpg';   // The file name suggestion for the user.
        document.body.appendChild(link);

        // Add each card element 
        photoHTML += '<article class="card animated fadeInLeft text-center">';
        photoHTML += '<img class="card-img-top img-responsive preview" src=' + photoBackground + '/>';
        photoHTML += '<div class="card-block">';
        photoHTML += '<h4 class="card-title" id="randomTitle"></h4>';
        photoHTML += '<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary dnme" id="div' + i +'">Download</button>'; // Create unique ID
        photoHTML += '</article>';

    })
    // End Card
    photoHTML += '</div>';
    // Put each card into a div
    $('#testing').html(photoHTML);
    // ? Somehow call specific card download id
    $(/* ID here */).click(function () {
        // Call download link
        link.click();
    });

  });
});
```

Comment: use class attribute . so it will $('.common_class').click(function () {
        currently_clicked_id  = $(this).attr('id');
        link.click();
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `class attribute` simplify the `multiple function` to one  otherwise you need click function for `each id` .

**HTML**

```
 photoHTML += '<button type="button" class="common_class btn btn-outline-primary dnme" id="div' + i +'">Download</button>'; // Create unique ID
```

**Jquery :**

```
$(document).on('click','.common_class',function () { 

     currently_clicked_id = $(this).attr('id'); 
     link.click(); 
});
```

Comment: Genius. Thank you!

Comment: glad to help you @Temple

Answer (score 0):

As the markup is getting generated dynamically then you need to delegate the event to the closest static parent:

```
$('#testing').on('click', '.dnme', function () {
    // Call download link
    link.click();
});
```

<sub>***NOTE: There are some duplicate ids. Ids should have to be unique.***</sub>

Comment: All ID's will be duplicate, that is the whole point of this question haha.